# Datatable sums 0 on SummaryRow

Tags: java, datatable, primefaces

I need to get the total of a set of transactions per day per hour bewteen two dates but only can get the result in the last of that dates. I'm using Java 8 with Primefaces 8.0. This is my code:

```xml
<p:dataTable id="dtLlamadas1" value="#{llamadaBean.lista1}" var="lista1"         sortBy="#{lista1.fecha}">

    (other primefaces tags)

    <p:summaryRow>
        <p:column colspan="2" style="text-align:right">
            <h:outputText value="Total:" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{lista1.totalTransacciones}">                                        
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:summaryRow>
</p:dataTable>
```

**lista1** is a Java List in a bean which contains a mapping of the table records (DATE, HOUR, TRANSACTIONS_PER_HOUR).

[Here is a sample of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwgBB.jpg)

As you can see, in other days the total is 0 but the last one. Does anybody can help me?

Comment: This piece of code is not a Java. Please edit your question.

Comment: Can you please create a small reproducible example using PrimeFaces Test so I can see your problem and debug it: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: @Coti i've never said that my code above was Java. I said LISTA1 was in a Java Bean which was used by it.

Comment: @Melloware i don't know if i used correctly that repository, but this is what i've done. Thanks for replying. https://github.com/davidsan1982/primefaces-test.git

Comment: When I run `mvn clean jetty:run` your example doesn't run and I can't see anything at the expected test page. http://localhost:8080/primefaces-test/test.xhtml

Comment: @Melloware I think it is because my app uses log and properties files for it's configuration. Besides, it uses data base connections to Oracle and PostgresSQL DB remote servers. Can you please refer to the image attached in this question for help me?

Comment: Nope I need an MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which is what the PF Test project is for. It takes all other variables out of the equation and lets a developer debug the problem.

Comment: @Melloware I've tried that MVCE you mentioned and my minimalist code worked. My mistake were inside a IF condition. Anyway, thank you very much for your help. It was helpfully.

Comment: Awesome that is why we  have people do MVCE. A lot of times it helps flush out bugs in their code by stripping everything down.

Comment: You should post your solution below so we can mark this ticket as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Melloware i've solved my problem. Here's my datatable defined in my xhmtl page:

```html
<p:dataTable id="Opcion1" value="#{llamadaBean.lista1}" var="lista1" rows="50"                      
                         sortBy="#{lista1.fecha}">
                <p:column headerText="FECHA">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{lista1.fecha}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="HORA">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{lista1.hora}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="TRANSACCIONES">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{lista1.numTransacciones}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:summaryRow>
                    <p:column colspan="2" style="text-align:right">
                        <h:outputText value="Total:" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{lista1.totalTransacciones}">                                        
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:summaryRow>
            </p:dataTable>
```

This means it will total all transactions by date. Meanwhile my bean was defined as follows:

```java
while (rs.next()) {
                numFila++;
                
                Llamada llamadaOp1 = new Llamada();

                llamadaOp1.setFecha(rs.getString("FECHA"));
                llamadaOp1.setHora(rs.getString("HORA"));
                llamadaOp1.setNumTransacciones(rs.getInt("TRANSACCIONES"));

                cont += rs.getInt("TRANSACCIONES");

                //get the total by day

                if(numFila>=24 || rs.isLast()){
                    llamadaOp1.setTotalTransacciones(cont);
                    cont=0;
                    numFila=0;
                }

                listaOp1.add(llamadaOp1);
            }
```

The problem was in **llamadaOp1.setTotalTransacciones(cont)** because it compared **numFila>=23** when HORA was still in the 23:00 hour, therefore **llamadaOp1.setTotalTransacciones(cont)** will set 0 in the 00:00 hour. I'm newbie in primefaces so i believe that the bug was there.